Enviar mensaje a multiples chats en telegram API
Necesito un poco de ayuda.
Tengo actualmente un script que me envia algunos datos de un formulario, sin embargo necesito que se envíe a 2 chats de Telegram, mi código actualmente es este:
 $botToken="0000000000:AAaaAAaAaAaaBBbBbbb-CcC";

    $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
    $chatIds= array("@canal1","@canal2");
    foreach($chatIds as $chatId) {    
    $params=[
        'chat_id'=>$chatId, 
//send text message with the data from the form
        'text'=> "Mensaje a enviar a los 2 usuarios"
    ];
    }
    $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

Sin embargo actualmente solo se envía al canal2 no se envía al canal 1.
Que puede ser que me fallo?

No pasa nada.. por eso vine a avisar rapido!! borro los comentarios...

Claro que nada más le va a mandar al canal2 porque en el foreach se está reescribiendo el array $params por cada ciclo. Cuando terminan todas las iteraciones, esa variable solo tendrá el último elemento de $chatIds y entonces es cuando entra a la fase CURL.
Para corregir el comportamiento solo tienes que cambiar } donde cierra el ciclo foreach:
$botToken = "0000000000:AAaaAAaAaAaaBBbBbbb-CcC";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
$chatIds = array("@canal1","@canal2");
foreach($chatIds as $chatId) {    
    $params = [
        'chat_id'=>$chatId, 
        //send text message with the data from the form
        'text'=> "Mensaje a enviar a los 2 usuarios"
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    sleep(1);
} 


Gracias, funciono bien, andaba dormido
